# In-function transformation side-effects on input arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have something like this:

```
object MyObject {
    var element1 /**/
    var element2 /**/
    var myOtherObject: OtherObject = new OtherObject
}

object MyOtherObject {
    var something1 /**/
    var something2 /**/
    var myList: List[T] = List()
}

def myUpdateFunction(iMyObject: MyObject) : SomeObject = {
    var myCopiedObject = iMyObject

    myCopiedObject.myList.dropRight
    /*checkpoint*/

    val myAwesomeOtherObject = new MyOtherObject
    /*perform multiple tasks to update myAwesomeOtherObject members*/

    myAwesomeOtherObject
}
```

When I check `myUpdateFunction` execution on the "checkpoint" commented line, I observe my `myCopiedObject.myList`has successfully been transformed, but that my `iMyObject` has too, ie. `iMyObject.myList` got truncated by one.

I do not understand how this can happen.

Any clue, anyone?

By the way, I am using `spark`

Comment: iMyObject is a reference to that instance of MyObject.  You're assignment to myCopiedObject is purely just reference based.  You need to make a new copy of iMyObject.

Comment: Using `var` in Scala is considered a bad practice, so avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you're just assigning the same object to another reference. `myCopiedObject` is not a copy of your object. You should write a method, that will create a new instance of `MyObject` using the same values as `iMyObject` holds.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myCopiedObject = iMyObject
```

The above code does not create a copy of the object. You are basically referring to same object but using a different reference.

Use `case class` and use `copy` method to create copy with required changes

```
case class Something(list: List[Int])

val sthing = Something(List(1, 2))
val copy = sthing.copy(list = sthing.list.take(1)) //creating changed copy using copy method
```